# HtmlAgilityPack WebGet.Load gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am on a project about getting new car prices from dealers websites. I can fetch most web sites html. But when I try to load one of them WebGet.Load(url) method gives `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. I couldn't find any differences between these web sites.

Normal working url examples :

`http://www.renault.com.tr/page.aspx?id=1715`

`http://www.hyundai.com.tr/tr/Content.aspx?id=fiyatlistesi`

website problematic :

```
http://www.fiat.com.tr/Pages/tr/otomobiller/grandepunto_fiyat.aspx
```

Thank you for your help.

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();  
var document = webGet.Load("http://www.fiat.com.tr/Pages/tr/otomobiller/grandepunto_fiyat.aspx");
```

When I use this url document is not loaded.

Comment: Can you post the full stack frame?

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is in HtmlAgilityPack internals. The page not working has this meta content type: `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=8859-9">` where `charset=8859-9` seems to be incorrent. The HAL internals tries to get an appropriate encoding for this string by using something like `Encoding.GetEncoding("8859-9")` and this throws an error (I think the actual encoding should be `iso-8859-9`).

Actually all you need is to tell the HAL not to read encoding for the `HtmlDocument` (just `HtmlDocument.OptionReadEncoding = true`), but this seems to be impossible with `HtmlWeb.Load` (setting `HtmlWeb.AutoDetectEncoding` isn't work here). So, the workaround could be in a manual reading of the url (the simplest way):

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.OptionReadEncoding = false;

var url = 
   new Uri("http://www.fiat.com.tr/Pages/tr/otomobiller/grandepunto_fiyat.aspx");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        document.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
    }
}
```

This works, and successfully parses the page.

**EDIT:** @:Simon Mourier: yes, it raises `NullReferenceException` because it catches `ArgumentException` and sets `_declaredencoding = null` there. And then `_declaredencoding.WindowsCodePage` line throws the null reference.

here is a code block from the HtmlDocument.cs, `ReadDocumentEncoding` method:

```
try
{
    _declaredencoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    _declaredencoding = null;
}
if (_onlyDetectEncoding)
{
    throw new EncodingFoundException(_declaredencoding);
}

if (_streamencoding != null)
{
    if (_declaredencoding.WindowsCodePage != _streamencoding.WindowsCodePage)
    {
        AddError(
            HtmlParseErrorCode.CharsetMismatch,
            _line, _lineposition,
            _index, node.OuterHtml,
            "Encoding mismatch between StreamEncoding: " +
            _streamencoding.WebName + " and DeclaredEncoding: " +
            _declaredencoding.WebName);
    }
}
```

And here is my stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=HtmlAgilityPack
  StackTrace:
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.ReadDocumentEncoding(HtmlNode node) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1916
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.PushNodeEnd(Int32 index, Boolean close) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1805
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Parse() in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1468
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 769
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(Stream stream, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 597
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1515
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, WebProxy proxy, NetworkCredential creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1563
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url, String method) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1152
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1107
       at test.console.Program.Main(String[] args) in W:\Projects\Me\test.console\test.console\Program.cs:line 54
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: The read encoding detection does not raise a NullReferenceException, but an ArgumentException, at least with HAP 1.3.0.0 (hence my question about the full stack frame)

Comment: @Simon: updated my answer with my stack trace (my version is 1.4.0.0).

Comment: Ok, so this is a bug introduced in 1.4.0.0.

Comment: @Alex Is this fixed already? Since I'm getting this in 1.4.9 as well. The workaround with explicit encoding set worked, so I'm fine. Just to make sure other programmers don't get this anymore

Comment: @kazarp: it seems that this is not fixed unfortunately