# htmlagility pack fails to fetch localhosted page

Tags: c#, unit-testing, html-agility-pack

I try to run the following code:

```
 public void Init(Url rootUrl)
        {
             var web = new HtmlWeb();
            this.doc = web.Load(rootUrl.Value);
        }
```

with the following param:

```
{<System.Security.Policy.Url version="1">
<Url>http://localhost:85/HCM/HCM.html</Url>
</System.Security.Policy.Url>
}
```

and get the following exception:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Stack Trace:

```
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.ReadDocumentEncoding(HtmlNode node) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1916
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.PushNodeEnd(Int32 index, Boolean close) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1805
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Parse() in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1492
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 769
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(Stream stream, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 597
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1515
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, WebProxy proxy, NetworkCredential creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1563
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url, String method) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1152
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1107
   at Conduit.CPServices.Logic.HtmlContentMonitor.HtmlAgilityPackHtmlProvider.Init(Url rootUrl) in D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CP\CPServices\Logic\HtmlContentMonitor\Conduit.CPServices.Logic.HtmlContentMonitor\HtmlAgilityPackHtmlProvider.cs:line 22
   at Conduit.CPServices.Logic.HtmlContentMonitor.HtmlContentManager.FetchRootAndExternlContentAsByteArray(Url rootUrl) in D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CP\CPServices\Logic\HtmlContentMonitor\Conduit.CPServices.Logic.HtmlContentMonitor\HtmlContentManager.cs:line 112
```

Comment: What URL are you actually using? Is it accessible locally through the browser?

Comment: `http://localhost:85/HCM/HCM.html` and it's accessible locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in HtmlAgilityPack which could be caught e.g. if document encoding set through the `<META>` tag is invalid (e.g. `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=8859-9">`). As Simon Mourier [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767318/htmlagilitypack-webget-load-gives-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance/5953331#comment6898877_5953331), this is a bug introduced in 1.4.0.0.

See the answer to the similar error: [The HAL internals tries to get an appropriate encoding for this string by using something like `Encoding.GetEncoding("8859-9")` and this throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5953331/102112).

To avoid this set the encoding manually, e.g.:

```
web.Load(rootUrl.Value, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
```

Comment: Does the Load() method throw this exception in this case Alex? I am using HAP 1.4.6 and my document appears empty but LoadFile() just executes without any exception nor ParseErrors?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a bug in HtmlAgilityPack, and it's likely due to the HTML contained in your document.

Can you post the HTML being parsed by HtmlAgilityPack?