# NullReferenceException in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract a `link` using `xpath` from the below mentioned url

```
string url = "http://www.album-cover-art.org/search.php?q=Ruin+-+Live+Album+Version+Lamb+of+God"
```

My code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc = web.Load(url); //Exception generated here Line 23

if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
  HtmlNode linkNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='related_search_row']/img/@src");
  if (linkNode != null)
        Console.WriteLine(linkNode.InnerText);
}
```

The above code compiles fine but when I try to run it generates a exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Complete stacktrace

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.ReadDocumentEncoding(HtmlNode node) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1916
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.PushNodeEnd(Int32 index, Boolean close) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1805
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Parse() in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1468
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs:line 769
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1515
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, WebProxy proxy, NetworkCredential creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1563
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url, String method) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1149
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1107
   at ScreenScrapping.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\ranveer\csharp\ScreenScrapping\ScreenScrapping\Program.cs:line 23
```

So, my question is why I am getting this exception.

Comment: With the version `1.4.3` of the HtmlAgilityPack your sample is working fine. Which version do you use?

Comment: @nemesv: Now i am using HtmlAgilityPack ver1.4.3. Now I am not getting any error but `Console.WriteLine(linkNode.InnerText);
` is not giving any output and neither `linkNode` is null I checked that.

Comment: When I use xpath `//title/text()` it works fine but when i switch to xpath expressions involving acccess of attributes using `/@href or /@src` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in HtmlAgilityPack. The document you're trying to parse has `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-utf-8">` where the `charset` value (`iso-utf-8`) couldn't be parsed as a valid encoding name by AgilityPack. As Simon Mourier [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767318/htmlagilitypack-webget-load-gives-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance/5953331#comment6898877_5953331), *this is a bug introduced in 1.4.0.0*.

To avoid this, manually load your document from a stream and set the encoding manually like this:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionReadEncoding = false;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked fine.  Now i am using HtmlAgilityPack ver1.4.3. Now I am not getting any error but `Console.WriteLine(linkNode.InnerText);
` is not giving any output and neither `linkNode` is null I checked that.

Comment: When I use xpath `//title/text()` it works fine but when i switch to xpath expressions involving acccess of attributes using `/@href or /@src` it doesn't work.

Comment: @Noob, try using it like "//a[@href]" - use square brackets for attributes

Comment: I tried `.//*[@id='related_search_row'][1]/img/[@src]` but it is generating an error `Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`.

Comment: I found a workaround using xpath `.//*[@id='related_search_row'][1]/img` than using `string val = linkNode.Attributes["src"].Value`. I was wondering is this the only way.

Comment: @Noob, remove a slash before "[@src]"

Comment: Now on using `.//*[@id='related_search_row'][1]/img[@src]` it is printing nothing in my console.

Comment: @Noob: it seems I understand what you trying to do. Xpath here selects nodes. If you want to get the attribute , use "GetAttribute" method. And BTW it's better to start a new question

Comment: `linkNode.GetAttribute("src","null")` worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason i was trying to use `.//*[@id='related_search_row'][1]/img/@src` is in `python lxml library` it worked fine and I got the desired value. So, I supposed the same behaviour with `HtmlAgilityPack` but it seems it handles things differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It gave me clear idea why exception is being thrown.