# descendant::* works but descendant::th gives error

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to make some simple programs that uses HtmlAgilityPack. The following program detects if words 'Address' or 'Phone' exist as contents of a 'th' tag.

I am running this program in Visual Studio 12.

The program as it is shown below gives an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in >StructureClassifier.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Kindly, notice the line

```
            var cells = table.SelectNodes("descendant::th");
```

If I replace this line by

```
            var cells = table.SelectNodes("descendant::*");
```

The program runs without any error.

Why is the below code not working?

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = w.Load("http://www.prouds.com.au/stores?state=WA")

        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            var cells = table.SelectNodes("descendant::th"); // This returns error
            //It would work if I were to replace descendant::th to descendant::*
            Console.Write(cells.Count);
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
            {
                string text = cell.InnerText;
                text = text.Trim();
                var equal = text.Equals("Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                if (equal)
                {
                    Console.Write("Found Match\n");
                    Console.Write(text);
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
                equal = text.Equals("Phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                if (equal)
                {
                    Console.Write("Found Match\n");
                    Console.Write(text);
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: could it be a bug in HtmlAgilityPack? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151993/nullreferenceexception-in-htmlagilitypack

Comment: If it is an error, it's not the same as the one in the link you gave. I tried using 1.4.6.0 and manually loaded the document from the stream as suggested by the top voted answer. Still getting the error.