# Parsing RSS feed from XML document

Tags: c#, html, xml

I'm trying to read RSS feed, but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to get content from td tag, but code always throws NullReferenceException while parsing table rows. Any help is appreciated.
Code:

```csharp
    public void readRss()
    {
        string Url = "mylink.com";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
        var rows = table.SelectNodes("//tr");
        if (rows != null && rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var cells = row.SelectNodes("//td");
                //do stuff
                
            }
        } 
    }
```

XML file is formatted like this:

```xml
    <![CDATA[<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>LastName</td>
            <td>Age</td>
       <tr>
    </table>
    ]]>
```

Comment: `always throws NullReferenceException while parsing table rows` on what line does this happen? Does your variable `table` contain anything or is it `null`? If you get back a node for `table`, what does your variable `rows` contain?

Comment: @Codexer It happens on the same line I have code for parsing rows. I tried debugging and table seems to be null too :(

Comment: Did you try to read the RSS feed using any of the existing Nuget packages that offers this functionality? Since we do not know which URL you want to read we cannot verify if the content is exactly as you state it is. By using a package of which we know it works, you can at least verify the link provides a readable RSS feed.

Comment: You only posted a section of the response.  Is the CDATA in side an XML response of a HTML response?  You first have to get the parent element before you can extract the CDATA data.

Comment: I resolved the issue by downloading the contents of the file to a string.Apart from getting the xml file,I didn't replace any of the code and it worked perfectly :/ I still had to remove the CDATA,which didn't help before.

Answer (score 0):

Does your web.Load(Url) is respond with the example XML file example? If it does then selecting nodes within CDATA will simply not work. The content within CDATA[...] is treated as text only and none of its content will form part of the document node tree. Therefore, your first **SelectSingleNode("//table")** will always give you a null result.
BTW: you should be testing for null value after setting the table and doc variables, just as you do for the rows.  Both of these, can return null.

Comment: Removing CDATA didn't help either. I had to download file to string, remove CDATA and then my code worked perfectly. Using Streams as per this answer also worked : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152191/12539617  Still don't know what the problem was. Encoding didn't seem to be an issue.