# C# Grabbing text within html tags

Tags: c#, html, tags

okay I am interested in trying to find the text between these tags:

```
<font color="#00006b">Aa Megami-sama (OAV 2011)</font>
```

And I have a list with names in the same tags, I want to grab them and put them into a dynamic array list.

I have tried to do this using HTMLAgilityPack but when I run my program this happens:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LoadHtml() Method takes HTML as input, not a URL. You need to fetch the HTML yourself.

For example:

```
        using (var webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            var html = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?list=A");

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//font");
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! FINALLY I can move forward, thanks guys for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectSingleNode()` is returning `null` value. So you need to do a "null check" for the last line. Do like this:

```
if(node != null)
{
   Messagebox.Show(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: This is what I did http://i.imgur.com/HysKg.png but it still is giving me problems. (It will never actually go to the else statement.)

Comment: then there may be problem in your HTML file. Ensure that the font has proper tag closings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use the LoadHtml method this way to get the html file data.

```
var webclient = new WebClient();
HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webClient.DownloadString(@"http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?list=A"));
```

Now this may not work sometimes as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767318/htmlagilitypack-webget-load-gives-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance) due to the possible invalid metadata charset. In such a case, you can use the answer there where the workaround is to manually read the response (by `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`).

---

Next, you may need to detect and handle other parse errors (including the one above) if any this way as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack):

```
   if (doc.ParseErrors!=null && doc.ParseErrors.Count>0)
   {
       // Handle any parse errors as required
   }
   else
   {
        if (doc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            HtmlNode fontNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//font");
            if (fontNode != null)
            {
                // Do something with fontNode
                MessageBox.Show(fontNode.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
```